Re-enryption Failure VMware Workstation Pro 17
Am currently using lastest version of Workstation (17.5.2). On my Win 11 machine after the last few upgrades, I keep getting the following message: "The virtual machine is encrypted using old encryption algorithm. You can upgrade VM to latest encryption mode. ..."
When I try to upgrade, I get the following error message: "Failed to reencrypt virtual machine. Please restart VMware Workstation and try again later."
I am not required to enter a password (and frankly didn't know I had an encrypted machine). I don't want a password either. This Win 11 VM works fine if I decline to upgrade the encryption.
I'd like to continue using this machine, but wonder if it will eventually cause me problems. If so, I would rather build a new virtual machine so I don't lose all my work on this machine.
Should I continue using this VM using the old encryption algorithm?

Can you disable encryption instead of upgrade it?

The encryption is for the virtual TPM (which normally is required for a Windows 11 guest), and I believe using a vTPM encrypts only part of the VM (notably, not the virtual disks).  See https://core.vmware.com/vtpm-questions-answers (which is written for vSphere, but most of it should apply to Workstation as well).  As for your error, the UI log file (its location is listed in Help > About) might have additional details.  Note that a new log file will be generated every time you run Workstation, so you'd want to reproduce the problem first before inspecting the log.

Thanks for your comments. @Ramhound: No, it appears not.

@jamesdlin: Sadly, I just use vmWare without knowing a darned thing about it. This is the first time I've ever had a problem. I do see some problems in the vmWare log file which I will investigate further. Thanks for pointing me in this direction.
